# Walking distance as a fraction of the distance by bus.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

For the $1^{\text {st }}$ part of a journey, Group B walks while Group A takes the bus. For the $2^{\text {nd }}$ part of a journey, Group A walks while Group B takes the bus. The speed of the bus is $40 \mathrm{kph}$ when loaded and $50 \mathrm{kph}$ when empty. Walking speed is $4 \mathrm{kph}$. Given that both groups arrive at the same time, find the walking distance as a fraction of the distance by the bus.

I don't understand this question. Why does it matter what the speed of the bus is when it's empty if an empty bus does not factor into the speed of the journey of group B? Like, if you're not riding the bus, i.e. you're walking, why does the speed of an empty bus matter?

This is the given solution, and it doesn't explain why we use $\frac{d}{40}+\frac{d-w}{50}=\frac{w}{4}$

Let the distance travelled by the bus be $d$ and by walking be $w$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\frac{d}{40}+\frac{d-w}{50}=\frac{w}{4} \\
&\frac{d}{w}=\frac{6}{1} \\
&\frac{w}{d}=\boxed{\frac{1}{6}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: The bus drives a certain distance with group A, then drops off group A who walk the rest of the way. The bus then drives back (unloaded) to collect group B, who have been walking all this time. The bus drives on to the destination carrying group B, who arrive just at the same times as group A.

Comment: @tomi right, so how do we get ${d \over 40} + {d-w \over 50}={w \over 4}$?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know how to find time given distance and speed?

Comment: These are two time calculations of how long it is before group B is picked up. The first is by the bus' journey, and second by group B's journey.